# Inserting values from sql query into a table column along with other data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have just created this table:

```
create table dbo.OrderTypes
(
ID smallint primary key identity,
Name varchar(300) not null,
CreatedOn datetime default getdate(),
CreatedBy nvarchar(300) not null,
ModifiedOn datetime default getdate(),
ModifiedBy nvarchar(300) not null
)
```

What I am trying to do is populate the Name field with results from this query:

```
select distinct ordertype from unit_results
```

as well as inserting CreatedBy and ModifiedBy by hand (they will be the same for every row).

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: I would suggest that you default the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy columns to something like system_user.  Then you won't have to supply those values when a row is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderTypes (Name, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy)
SELECT DISTINCT ordertype, 'CreatedBy Value Here', 'ModifiedBy Value Here'
FROM unit_results
```